# Azure ARM Template - accessing a resource Id created by one ARM template in another ARM template

Tags: json, azure, octopus-deploy, azure-resource-manager

We deploy azure resources using an ARM template as part of our build process before deploying the actual application.

*So far all our application resources are self contained within a `resource group`. e.g. A web app that requires a sql server and a storage account are clubbed into one resource group.*

*However we have come across a scenario/need where we need to share a resource eg. storage account across resource groups. Resource Group A has the storage account and Resource Group B's web app requires the connection string/app keys pertaining to the storage account in its `appconfig.json/web.config`.*

**Question**

**How do I build the connection string for the app in resource group B to connect to a resource in resource group A as I need to obtain the Id of the resource group A in B**

Here is how i build the connection string if they are in the same resource group

```
  "variables"
{
  "storageAccounts_id": "[concat(**resourceGroupA**().id,'/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccntName'))]",
},
"resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "type": "config",
      "name": "connectionstrings",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('MyWebSiteName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
      "AzureWebJobsDashboard": {
        "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',variables('storageAccntName'),';AccountKey=',concat(listKeys(variables('storageAccounts_id'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1))]",
        "type": "Custom"
      },
      }
    }
  ]
```

Notes:
I did go through this site https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-linked-templates/ about linked templates, but it does not suit our current build process which uses `Octo` (*unless there is something I may be missing*) which deployes the ARM first then the application (web).

Comment: did you ever get anything working for this?

Answer (score 18):

For this scenario where the storage account name is known and does not depend on the resource group (eg, uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)), then you can simply use the longer form for [resourceId()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#resourceid).  The full form looks like:

```
resourceId([subscriptionId], [resourceGroupName], resourceType, resourceName1, [resourceName2]...)
```

so we can optionally supply subscriptionId and resourceGroupName.

```
listKeys(resourceId(parameters('ResourceGroupAName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('ccPaymentStorageName'))
```

If it was in a different subscription, you could also specify the subscription.

```
listKeys(resourceId(parameters('SubscriptionId'), parameters('ResourceGroupAName'), 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('ccPaymentStorageName'))
```

If your storage account name depends on the resource group like

```
"storageName": "[concat('mystorage', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]" // in Resource Group A
```

then you'll either need to always run the template that creates this account and output the storageName and the resourceGroup or find a way to reference the other resource group to get it's id so that the name can be re-created.

I have been able to use something like this to "re-create" the resource group id so I can generate the proper name of the storage account.

```
"otherResourceGroupId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('ResourceGroupName'))]"
```

Then I can use that to generate the name appropriately:

```
"storageAccountName": "[concat('mystorage', uniqueString(variables('otherResourceGroupId')))]"
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try below(for an example ):-

"subNetId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('virtualNetworkNameRG'), '/providers/', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/',parameters('virtualNetworkName'),'/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]",

refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions

Comment: Please inspect your answer, something appears to be missing in item 2.

Comment: This does not work.  You cannot just put a Resource Group Name concat with ().id and hope for anything good.  Also, resourceId requires a type and a name.  The subscription and group name parameters are optional.  There is no way to specify just the resource group, from what I can tell.